# Como manter os dados da checkbox PHP?

Tags: php, html

como deixo permanentemente salvo na checkbox

----\

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<form action="">
<input type="checkbox" name="box" value="Bike">Pago<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="box" value="Car">Nao Pago 
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Coloca `checked="checked"` no input

Comment: Muito obrigado, mas teria como salvar a opção selecionada, para que outra pessoa possa visualizar  ?  ou tenho que fazer a ligação com o banco de dados e depois puxar essa dado para a pagina.

Answer (score 0):

Basta adicionar o atributo `checked` do input dessa forma já vem marcado quando a página for aberta.

**Leitura recomendada:**

[MDN - checkbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/checkbox)